# Determine whether the series is divergent or convergent and find its sum.

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

Any tips on how to start this would be great. I'm aware its not geometric but the answer key indicates it diverges, however I have no idea how to physically show that with this equation.
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\tan\frac{3\pi n}4$$
Perhaps the test for divergence is all I need to find the conclusion to this question?

Comment: I'm still confused as to how that proves its divergent.

Comment: If it does not converge, it is divergent. It cannot converge since it includes undefined terms.

Comment: @LukeD If a sequence $\{a_n\}$ is convergent then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}a_n=0$ now try it's negation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $n=2$ term is undefined (Mathematica's "complex infinity"), so the series diverges.